# Eureka server with Spring Cloud load balancer is not working with lb:instance name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-netflix

We have implemented a micro service architecture having **Eureka discovery server**,**spring cloud API gate way**,**Spring cloud config server** and a **microservice rest API**.
These are working very well now.The next step am planed to enable the  spring cloud load balancer.
I prefer the load balancer inside the **gate way**.When i run the while applications,all services are registered in the **eureka server**.Refer the screen short
[image]

Gate way routing implemented like below

```
@Configuration
public class RequestRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes().route(r -> r.path("/service-one/**")
                .uri("lb://MICROSERVICE-ONE/")).build();

    }
}
```

On the routing URI i refer lb with application name which shown in the eureka server.

When i send a request to the microservice rest API .The gateway log says

```
2022-07-01 23:11:38.690  WARN 36552 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: MICROSERVICE-ONE
2022-07-01 23:13:51.921 ERROR 36552 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [d26ed93f-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/service-one/list"

io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$SearchDomainUnknownHostException: Failed to resolve '<domain name>' and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [abc.org]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/service-one/list" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:1113) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:992) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$3.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:512) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1055) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:971) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:467) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) [netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:240) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:192) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Have checked registered application info from erukea server using **http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps**  and the output will be like this

```
<application>
<name>MICROSERVICE-ONE</name>
<instance>
<instanceId><domain name>:microservice-one:9078</instanceId>
<hostName>INLC4GQZH3.nlsn.media</hostName>
<app>MICROSERVICE-ONE</app>
<ipAddr>192.168.1.4</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">9078</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
```

**Versions Used**

1. spring boot  : 2.7.0
2. spring cloud : 2021.0.3

what was the mistake i made here.
suggest a better solution.Spend a lot of time on the top this issue, could not resolve it .

Thanks in advance